# What does it mean "shell integration failed to activate" in vscode?

Tags: javascript, powershell, visual-studio-code

So, I have been trying to run a Javascript program in VScode and I keep getting this pop up on right side of the terminal window. "shell integration failed to activate" along with a whole bunch of other BS above it. What does it mean and how to solve this problem?

[image: screen shot of error message on VScode]

I have pasted "shell integration failed to activate" in chatgpt and it suggests a few solutions like "check node.js installation" "check environment variables" "restart vscode" etc. but none of these work and the problem is still there. Why is this happening, and how can this issue be resolved? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179529

Comment: Java is launching a shell to run powershell.exe.  The powershell script shellintegration.ps1 is not working.  I would try to run shellintgegration.ps1 from PS and get working before you try to run from Java.  Start by debugging first error message in the ps1 script.  This is not a Java issue.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) [edit] to describe exactly how you are trying to run the JS program. is it a launch config? are you trying to just run commands in the terminal? 3) How exactly is this terminal being opened? are you opening it manually by opening the terminal panel and powershell is your default terminal profile? is it opening in order to run a task or a launch config?